# NodeJS and Queue Messaging service

Tags: socket.io, rabbitmq, node-redis, socketcluster

In my node project, I need to have a process that read all the data from a queue and rebroadcast the data in real-time through websockets to all subscribed clients. I was wondering if it was possible to achieve something like that with Redis? I might have several servers that pushes data into that queue.

What would be the right approach and tools to achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing that with SocketCluster.  Rather than have a queue, I'll probably just have the servers connect to SocketCluster directly.

So yes,

```
Browsers <-> SocketCluster <-> Queue or direct messaging
                   |
                 Redis
```

Note that Redis is used by SocketCluster for clustering.  It may not be the best way to queue your messages.